# Is there a large and varied syslog corpus available for download

Tags: data-request

I'm looking for large amounts of varied syslog data for testing a log analysis tool.

Wishlist:

- Logs from different Unices and Linux distributions
- Logs from routers, switches, storage arrays, firewalls, IDS and appliances
- Logs from different countries and industries
- Logs spanning several years

Google searching has only given me small sets of fairly repetitive logs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Loghub maintains a collection of system logs, which are freely accessible for research purposes. Some of the logs are production data released from previous studies, some others are collected from real systems in our lab environment. Wherever possible, the logs are NOT sanitized, anonymized or modified in any way."

https://github.com/logpai/loghub

Comment: Still early days, but I hope they get traction.

Comment: This is spam. The GitHub is just links to go register to a company website to get access to the actual data.

Comment: RE Spam, I see log files in the Github repo... https://github.com/logpai/loghub/blob/master/Zookeeper/Zookeeper_2k.log. Please clarify

Comment: Yeah, I can't find any spam either.

Answer (score 0):

The company Splunk maintains a Boss of the SOC dataset, which powers a large capture the flag exercise. The exercise is Splunk-focused, the data is not. The dataset contains data generated from the entire stack of devices often found in an enterprise network. You can find it here https://github.com/splunk/botsv3